# Symfony 3.4 - Use array as name for input fields

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-3.4

I have a form, and inside this form, I need to display several dynamic fields.

My problem is I want a structure like :

```
<input name="my_form[PARAM1][active]" />
<input name="my_form[PARAM2][active]" />
```

For now, in my Form, I use a simple loop :

```
foreach ($options['myParams'] as $param) {
    $builder->add('Param'. $param['id'] .'Active', TextType::class, [
        'label' => $param['title'],
    ]);
}
```

But I don't have the structure I want. I see the option `property_path` in Symfony 5, but not in 3.4... I tried with CollectionType, but I am not sure it's possible with 2 nested inputs.